# Best-practice/most elegante way to get urls on a jsp

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp, spring-boot

I have the following issue:
I'm using Spring-MVC with JSPs. 
On my page I want to put a couple of links(with urls) in the content area. I'm getting the names of the links plus the description from a properties file via spring:messages.

Now the question is, what is the best-practice or most elegant way to put the link-urls on the page. Should I hardcode them in the jsp? Should they come from the properties file where I have stored the text which goes on the page, should they come from the controller (where they would be stored in static variables) or should they be passed through all the way using a service and a bean etc.?

I would appreciate your opinion!

Comment: Well it depends. Are those url's gonna change frequently? Do you want to be able to change it's values just by editing a *.properties, *.xml or *.json file? Does the content of the page change depending on the user? (like loading more links when scrolling)

Comment: I guess they won't change that often.
But I guess hardcoding them in the JSP is not the best practice, isn't it? Shouldn't the jsp only be responsible for view issues and visualisation, while all the content including links comes from the system?

Comment: You're right but you should follow that principle with caution. If you're too strict then it'll take a lot of time to do anything. Making stuff configurable / dynamic depends on frequency of change. If those links should be changed by yourself only when the domain or something else changes, then use a configuration file like *.properties.